# Override properties of an existing global interface

Tags: typescript

I want to override the type of the first argument of window.localStorage.setItem so that only limited values are accepted:

```
export {};

declare global {
  interface Storage {
    setItem(key: 'a' | 'b', value: string): void;
  }
}
```

However this is still possible: `localStorage.setItem('foo', value)`

Is there a way to override the Storage interface property or should I create a wrapper function over localStorage.setItem instead?

Comment: You can only add signatures not remove them. Your augmentation introduces an overload but does not and can not remove the existing signature. Also note that `localStorage.setItem(k, v)` is equivalent to `localStorage[K] = v`. Your consideration of a wrapper is sensible.